# Issue during reading a CSV file has me stumped

Tags: java, csv, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to write a method that simply reads in a CSV file and stores the data from the file. Here is a link to a screenshot of the CSV file I am trying to read in, and the code for this method:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jrhw.png

```
public static void correctPrices(String correctfile) {

    String data;
    Date date;
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

    File correctedfile = new File(correctfile);
    Scanner correct;

    try {

        correct = new Scanner(correctedfile);

        correct.nextLine(); //to avoid reading the heading
        ArrayList<Date> correctdate = new ArrayList<Date>();
        ArrayList<String> correctdata = new ArrayList<String>();

        while (correct.hasNext()) {

            correctdata.add(correct.nextLine());
            //data = correct.nextLine();
            //String[] corrected = correct.nextLine().split(",");
            //date = formatter.parse(corrected[0]);
            //correctdate.add(date);

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < correctdata.size(); i++) {

            System.out.println(correctdata.get(i));

        }

    } 

    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {

        Logger.getLogger(DataHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

    }        

}
```

As expected, this code would output the last 2 lines of the file. However, when I un-comment data = correct.nextLine(); in the while loop, the output will only return the second line of the CSV, and not the last line. I'm a little baffled by this? All I've tried to do was to store the line into another variable, why would the last line be omitted? Thanks for your help and time, let me know if you need any additional info!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, when you call `correct.nextLine()`, it reads in a line and then increments a pointer in the file to where you are reading. Since you call that multiple times in the loop, it increments the pointer multiple times, skipping lines.  What you should do is just read the line once, in the beginning of the while loop using

```
data = correct.nextLine();
```

and then replace `correct.nextLine()` everywhere else it appears in the loop with `data`.

In other words, your `while` loop would look like

```
while (correct.hasNext())
{
    data = correct.nextLine();
    correctdata.add(data);
    String[] corrected = data.split(",");
    date = formatter.parse(corrected[0]);
    correctdate.add(date);
}
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you. It makes sense once I look at it now, but I guess I was treating correct.nextLine() as a variable itself and didn't consider the pointer incrementing.

Comment: Yes, a common mistake. One of the many joys of stateful programming.